# Seeding grass with milorganite

Tags: lawn, grass, seeds, germination, fertilizer

I used weed killer almost 2 weeks ago and I think I am ready to seed and fertilize. My yard is around 9.000 sq ft and backyard gets lots of sun light but my trees block the half part so half part is shade and have almost no grass.(2000sq. ft.) My plan is seed then use milorganite. For shade part I think dense shade would be good the rest I can use shade & sun mix. Before seeding I will add some top soil. Any suggestions would be great. I haven't done any lawn care in my life.

Besides milorganite do I have to use anything else? Like turf starter etc?

Is it too late to seed now? I live in Kansas, it is end of may and weather the 70s.

Edit: I added some photos.

https://ibb.co/iVWZbT

https://ibb.co/npDrO8

https://ibb.co/mEGd38

https://ibb.co/bNuUbT

https://ibb.co/e2P6O8

https://ibb.co/fZgxVo

https://ibb.co/hwhFGT

https://ibb.co/mGpjAo

Comment: Please send a picture or two, Sami.  Milorganite is not a balanced fertilizer. I would apply this stuff now because fertilizer is necessary for your established grass.  Water it in well.  In a few days then over seed.  I need to see your lawn, we might be able to save you a lot of work.  It is fine to over seed now, hold off on the top soil for a bit.  No turf starter.  When was the last aeration?  You should go read other lawn questions and answers on this site soon and send a picture please..

Comment: Also, what weed killer did you use?  Read what it says about seeding.  It is usually 3 weeks or more depending on what product you used.

Comment: Thank you stormy! I added a couple photos. I don't know when was the last aeration. I bought this home 6 months ago and I had to clean a big mess first. at least 20 yard bags of trash :) Took days.. I am planning on aeration in September.

Comment: I used Southern Ag 2,4-D Amine Weed Killer Selective Broadleaf Weed Control but I didn't kill some plants or weeds whatever they are in my backyard close to fence line so for those plants I used Compare-N-Save Concentrate Grass and Weed Killer.

Comment: Ugh.  I am always amazed at what homeowners are allowed to purchase.  Gnarly stuff.  Here is the label that you have to read thoroughly.  We were taught in pesticide seminars and recertification/licensing to read the label 5X each and every time we used any product.  This says that you can reseed after 2 weeks.  The second one must by glyphosate and kills anything it touches.  No seeding there of course anyway but that would take at least 3 weeks before seeding.  Pesticide is a bandaid people use when they've made a big mistake.  One product I will endorse is Dr. Earth's Lawn Fertilizer.

Comment: https://southernag.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/AMINE-GL.pdf

Comment: Well. I read both labels twice and I used them based on peoples recommendations. It has been almost two weeks for Selective Broadleaf Weed Control and almost a week for grass and weed killer. I am still waiting for more time to seed. Thank you for your help and advice!

Comment: Good job, I figured that you had read them because of the two week reseed thing.  You are rare!  You get free EXPERT advice on this site about gardening.  Our team is amazing.  Read the other question answers about lawns on this site, you will start coming up with lots more questions that will be far more specific to your lawn and experience.  Always know that pesticides are never necessary...even if something has gotten out of control (usually because of an application of some pesticide).  Fertilizer is not pesticide.  FYI, grins.

Comment: I just looked at one of your pictures...ha ha ha.  Yeah, I'll be back soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Removing lawn replacing with 3/8 minus crushed gravel 4" thick over landscape fabric][image: residential plan getting rid of lawn]Let me try to make this an answer.  I need to help you think of other solutions rather than trying to grow grass under those trees.  Far better use of your money and time.  Forget trying to grow a lawn under those trees.

I have to pause and edit to be able to see all of the pictures.

Adding a couple of pictures for you to imagine.  In Japan, you won't find 'lawns' in the parks, just crushed gravel, crushed granite.  Wonderfully consistent, low maintenance, beautiful, crunchy alternative to a lawn.

Your lawn that does get sun needs raking to break up that dead debris (need to see closeups of cross section of lawn to determine if thatch is a problem), then mowing 'short' sucking up the debris before you seed.

This lawn looks like it hasn't been fertilized for awhile?  Thin.  What you do apply for fertilizer won't get through all that dead grass.  Let's talk more before you attack your problems.  Sure looks like an awful lot more than 9000 sq. ft.!?

Also, your entire fence is in jeopardy of needing replacement within 3 to 5 years.  See the dark line of moisture at the bottom of your fence?  That soil needs to be removed so there is at least 2" of air between fence and soil.

If you are interested in alternatives to lawn for shade, there are many choices.  Gravel is the easiest, prettiest and least expensive.

Comment: I really appreciate your time and advice stormy!! :) That's lot of great information. My plan is hire professionals and trim tress and 1-2 year max replace fence. I don't know when they fertilized my grass last time and since I bought this house I haven't done anything, it was winter time. I thought it was 9000 sq ft lot. When I bought the house it said on paper 10.000 sq ft and my house is two story 1500 sq ft so I thought it would be around 9000 sq ft. Thank you soo much!!

Comment: You are so very welcome.  If I were you and others who haven't had the time to learn about gardening, lawns, landscapes, I would bug the heck out of this site before spending a dime.  Seriously.  Make sure anyone you hire has insurance that protects your home insurance from being used. Get a few bids and recommendations before committing to a company.  Here is a formula to remember that will help with your bids; divide the square footage of anything by 81.  That will give you the amount of cubic yards for 4" of coverage whether topsoil, or gravel or sand.  If you need 2" then divide in half.